# Intercepting setValueAt() equivalent in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to transition to using JavaFX and off of Swing. I like the tables a lot and the great simplicity they offer (as well as the potential to create great builders and wrappers with lambdas). However, with the exception of ObservableList and some GUI behavioral applications, I'm not exactly thrilled with the data binding. I'm a big fan of immutability and my applications usually write all edits to a database and re-build the objects after re-pulling the edited data, rather than editing the objects directly.

Following Oracle's documentation, I leveraged the ReadOnlyObjectWrapper which works great. I even built some factory methods around it.

```
 firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
     public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p) {
         return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getFirstName());
     }
  });
```

However, what if I want to make it editable without using data binding? What if I want to intercept a new edited value and write it to a database rather than using a binded property? I guess what I'm getting at is there an old-school setValueAt() method that JTable's had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm) guide for editing and updating data (part "Editing Data in the Table").

On another way you can try use your own Cell Factory like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm). In my opinion this method is more flexible because I can update not only model if I need. Also I can customize input cell (it can be TextField or TextArea, etc.)

Comment: Okay, quick question. So if I want to go this route, the datatype for my columns are pretty much stuck with String since that is all TextField supports. So dates, numbers, etc... all must be converted to String for the table model?

Comment: As I understand - yes. I use TreeView from second link and in my own datatype class I overrided `.toString()` method where I return needed String for tree cell (in your case it will be table cell).